# Javascript Tablemodel Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I am looking for a JavaScript MVC table widget similar to [Java Swing TableModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)

I would also like to have two models, one totally local and one remote (XMLHttpRequest)

I would also like the view to accept text columns (and maybe HTML columns) and have these text columns HTML or CSS formatted depending the cell contents (just like you would be able in a Java Swing JTable)

Do you know of any implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could make it up yourself using these components which all partially solve your problem

http://jamal-mvc.com/ -> lightweight MVC

> Jamal is a set of conventions and
>   small javascript libraries to archieve
>   a complete separation of html, css and
>   javascript in your web application.
>   Jamal is built on  jQuery and inspired
>   by MVC frameworks like  Ruby on Rails,
>   CakePHP and its derivatives.
>
> The MVC concept is easy to adopt for
>   javascript
>
> Controller: Interaction with the user interface (events)
>
> Model: Business Logic and AJAX calls
>
> View: DOM, CSS modifications

[ActiveRecord JS](http://activerecordjs.org/record.html) -> DB connector

> ActiveRecord.js is a cross browser,
>   cross platform, stand-alone object
>   relational mapper. It shares a very
>   similar vocabulary to the Ruby
>   ActiveRecord implementation, but uses
>   JavaScript idioms and best practices
>   -- it is not a direct port. It can operate using an in memory hash table,
>   or with a SQL back end on the Jaxer
>   platform (SQLite and MySQL), Adobe's
>   AIR (SQLite) and Google Gears
>   (SQLite). Support for the HTML 5 SQL
>   storage spec is planned.

[jQuery tablesorter Plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) -> display table data (maybe you need to check if it supports or can be made to easily support editable cells)